# How to filter messages on kafka topic based on hostnames under message properties , where as consumers are on 2 different servers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement to consume messages from kafka based on hostname under message properties. Messages are getting dropped under Kafka topic from downstream and on the listener side 2 process are configured to same kafka queue but running on 2 different servers/hostnames. What is the procedure to filter out messages based on hostnames under properties to route messages to the right server. For example message 1 got property with hostname name as serverA and message 2 got property with hostname serverB . Message 1 should be picked up by server A and message 2 should be picked up by serverB.

Comment: Why do you need both hosts messages in the same topic?

Comment: Its a real time request and response design.  Server A and Server B listening to the requests and dropping those processed requests into Kafka queue along with hostnames in message properties. Downstream application picks the requests and will drop those processed data under response kafka queue. The requirement here is that response related to server A should be picked up by server A based on hostnames from response properties and response related to Server B should be picked up by Server B which were dropped under response queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to have 2 different topics for server A and server B. That way those can also scale independently. If you want those services to have one interface you can do it as follows with 3 topics:

1. services A + B interface - you will have a router that listens to this topic and route the message based on your business logic to topics A/B.
2. topic A - service A will listen to that one.
3. topic B - service B will listen to this one.

Both service A and B will write the output to your response topic.
In that approach topics A and B are internal mechanism of your backend system, your clients will only write to the interface topic.

Another approach would be to implement custom partitioner - I think that's an over kill for your use case and there are a lot of things to take into account such as skewed data.

Comment: Service A+B Interface -Are we suppose to create a Router on Kafka topic ? Please advise.

Comment: A consumer that consumer A+B interface, and based on the message field that says which service should handle that message (hostname) - produces the message to A/B topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the hostname as the record key in the producer, and define a static partitioner that routes certain host name patterns to specific partitions.

Then, the consumer would need to use `assign` rather than `subscribe` to read specific partitions.

Alternatively, just make different topics unless you plan on having thousands of them

Comment: Currently , the request and response Kafka queues got 10 partitions. will that approach still work with 10 partitioning's ?

Comment: The number of partitions doesn't matter. Do all messages for the same host need to be in the same partition? Then use the hostname as the record key and assign the consumer to the correct partitions

Comment: There is no requirement to process all messages in the same partition.

Comment: You said "Message 1 should be picked up by server A and message 2 should be picked up by serverB". Generally, that's only possible if those messages are in different partitions. I meant all records for the same host, not all messages from all hosts. All records for the same host should be in ordered in a single partition. The number of total partitions doesn't really matter in this case